# Locating base.py when working on Colab

Tags: python, nlp, language-model, colab

I have faced an error while working with langchain on colab. There is a post on github which recommends changing some configurations in

```
 local / repo find-> langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/pandas/base.py
```

Could you please let me know how I can find and configure base.py while working on colab?

Answer (score 0):

The required filepath is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/python/base.py
```

You can

1. Click 'File' icon on the left side, follow the above path, double-click on *base.py*, edit and save (Ctrl+S)
2. Or follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687091/how-to-edit-and-save-text-files-py-in-google-colab